# UDP server client is not sending complete files

Tags: python, python-3.x, udp, udpclient

we are doing a UDP transfer file client server but we can only send images of 11K, but if we try to send a video or a file with 10MB or 20, 100, 250, 500MB the problem only send 1/3 of the file size. Thank you for looking

Client:
https://github.com/JuanCamiloUsecheRodriguez/UDP-FT/blob/master/UDPClient.py

Server:
https://github.com/JuanCamiloUsecheRodriguez/UDP-FT/blob/master/UDPServer.py

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please have a look over the [guidelines on asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, please don't just link us to your entire code, but post just enough code to reproduce your specific problem in the question. Feel free to edit to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is not a reliable protocol. It is likely that you saturate the network with your bulk transfer, causing packets to get dropped.

You need to implement retransmission of dropped packets and, ideally, some form of congestion control, similar to what is part of [Transmission Control Protocol (TCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control) or the [Datagram Congestion Control Protocol (DCCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Congestion_Control_Protocol).